# Windows 10でPlaywrightライブラリを使ってブラウザを開こうとすると、triggerUncahughtExceptionが生じてすぐに閉じてしまう。

Tags: javascript

現在、JavaScriptでPlaywrightライブラリを用いて、以下のコードでブラウザを起動してE2Eテストを実行しようとしております。

```
import { chromium } from "playwright";
const launchOptions = {
    "headless":false,
    "channel":"chrome",
    "args": [
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--no-zygote"]
};

chromium.launch(launchOptions).then(async browser => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://google.com");
    await browser.close();
})
```

これを実行してみた所、以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

browserType.launch: Browser closed.
```

サンプルコードを実行してみたのですが、何かしらWindowsで用いる場合追加で設定が必要かどうか、ご存知の方居ましたらご教示頂けないでしょうか？

Comment: 何か基にした書籍やWeb記事があれば、それを示して同じにしても動かないとか、ここを変えたけど(あるいは変えたから)動かないとかの状況を追記してみてください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 他には検索して見つかるこんな記事と同じことを試してみてはどうでしょう？ [Playwright のミニマムなテスト。](https://crieit.net/posts/Playwright), [Playwrightを使って実際のブラウザ動作からE2Eテストを作ろう！](https://qiita.com/miruon/items/579d02eb26834259f034), [PlayWright を使ってE2Eテストを書いてみた](https://www.cresco.co.jp/blog/entry/14335.html), [PlayWrightを用いたテスト自動化](https://www.cresco.co.jp/blog/entry/20355.html)